# Are there a names for this condition patterns?

Tags: if-statement, design-patterns

There are two ways to ensure a condition is met:

- The simple way is using an`if` with the condition:

  ```
  if (condition)
  {
      /* execute code */
  }
  ```
- The other way is similar but I check for the negated condition and `return` if this is given:

  ```
  if (!condition)
  {
      return;
  }
  /* execute code */
  ```

Are there names for this patterns?
I tried googleing it but was not successfull...

Comment: It is called `"if" statement` - [if-else (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else)

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for this, but I consider this part of the recommendation to avoid too many levels of nesting of code blocks. By using the second form that you described above, you avoid further nesting for any other blocks inside of the `/* execute code */`. And the less nesting your code has (at least in my opinion) the easier it will be for somebody to understand your code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this pattern is called *early exit.*

Answer (score 1):

He was asking I believe for what the patterns are called in general so he could research them. They are called Conditional Logic. So if you google Conditional Logic Patterns... There are many responses on google.

Answer (score 1):

I use often it. But I don't know whether it has really a name.
I considerate it as a derived of [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).
It improves the readability by isolating the no nominal cases at the beginning and by leaving the nominal/classic case then.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are good, but there is a more precise name for the pattern. Let's review the other names first.

- Both examples are **conditional logic** so that name doesn't really help us differentiate the positive execution from the negative return.
- The negative return does constitute **early exit** but since there are other ways to achieve early exit, that name is not specific to this example.
- The negative return could be **fail-fast** but it's debatable whether `return` is necessarily failure. Throwing an exception would be a better example of fail-fast and would also constitute early exit.

The negative return is more precisely a [guard clause](http://wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause), which is also a [refactoring](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen multiple names for the second pattern in the wild (the one with the return statement)

- return early pattern
- guard clause pattern
- bouncer pattern

It's typically used to reduce the number of nesting levels in the code and helps with readability.